# Evaluate the Integral: $\int\frac{3t-2}{t+1}$

Tags: calculus

Evaluate the Integral: $\int\frac{3t-2}{t+1}$

1) Long division gives $\int3-\frac{5}{t+1}dt$

2)I take the negative and constant outside of the integral.

$-3\int\frac{5}{t+1}dt$

3) I then take the 5 out side the integral and multiply it by the three.

$-15\int\frac{1}{t+1}dt$

4) U-substitution

$u=t+1$ and $du=dt$

5) Integrate

$-15\ln|t|+C$

6) Replace $u$ with $t+1$

Final answer is $-15\ln|t+1|+C$

Am I correct if not please explain.

Comment: from Step 2 to Step 3 you are making a mistake. It should be
$\int 3 dt - \int \frac{5}{t+1} dt$

Comment: $$\int \left(3-\frac{5}{t+1}\right)dt = \int 3\,dt-\int\frac{5}{t+1}dt$$

Comment: @Mario That minus sign is important to indicate......?

Comment: @BenCarson2016 this property is the so called "Linearity of Integrals". In your calculation you are somehow changing a subtraction into a multiplication

Answer (score 1):

*Mistake* begins from **step 2**.

> $$\int3-\frac{5}{t+1}dt \not = -3\int\frac{5}{t+1}dt $$

It should be as follows:
$$\int(3-\frac{5}{t+1})dt$$
$$=3\int dt -5\int \frac{d(t+1)}{(t+1)}$$
$$=3t-5\ln\big|t+1\big|+c$$

Comment: Is the d(t+1) supposed to the in the numerator?

Comment: Yes of course. Any doubts?

Comment: I am just curious, why?

Comment: It is substitution only, nothing else. Check that $d(t+1)=dt$. You can also use this. It makes working faster i.e. you can write $3x^2dx=d(x^3)$ and you can calculate the integrals easier without taking $u,v,w,..$ and other variables for substitution, making it rather less messy.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
\int \left(3-\frac{5}{t+1}\right)\,dt&=\int 3\,dt-\int \frac{5}{t+1}\,dt\\
&=3t-5\ln|t+1|+C
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

$$\int\frac{3t-2}{t+1}\space\space\text{d}t=$$
$$\int\left(3-\frac{5}{t+1}\right)\space\space\text{d}t=$$
$$-5\int\frac{1}{t+1}\space\space\text{d}t+3\int 1\space\space\text{d}t=$$

---

Substitute $u=t+1$ and $\text{d}u=\text{d}t$:

---

$$-5\int\frac{1}{u}\space\space\text{d}u+3\int 1\space\space\text{d}t=$$
$$-5\ln\left(u\right)+3t+\text{C}=$$
$$-5\ln\left(t+1\right)+3t+\text{C}=$$
$$3t-5\ln\left(t+1\right)\text{C}$$

Comment: Quick comment, it should be $\ln|x|$ not $\ln(x)$